# Why do people always suggest command-line, config-file and ini-file solutions while there is also such thing as a user interface...?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes wonder why they still bother making user interfaces...

It seems like when you ask a question on stack-overflow the majority suggests a command-line, config-file or ini-file solution while often there is a more user friendly solution available simply by using the provided user interface. 
For example [this question about setting the timeout of `phpmyadmin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-to-not-time-out-so-quickly)

In this case there is also another UI-style answer available but the accepted answer with the most upvotes is in my opinion much more complicated then the suggested solution by `tfont` using the phpmyadmin settings panel.

More often the UI-style answer to a question is not present at all.

Are stack-overflow users generally not familiar with those UI-solutions?

Do they strongly prefer using their command-line and text-editor?

Or am I just too much of a noob and that's why i prefer those less nerdy UI-solutions?

Comment: One reason might be that command line solutions allow for automation via scripts etc. Something you can't do with a UI.

Comment: Well, for your example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-to-not-time-out-so-quickly#comment28769694_18886833

Comment: @Bart Nicely spotted! I missed that one. Legitimate reason I would say :)

Comment: I upvoted this discussion because too often, people who aren't familiar with a command will screw it up and the UI keeps you on safe ground.  Even if I am experienced in something, I will go to the UI because I am less likely to accidentally type in something wrong.  I actually wish more systems were developed with UI so that you can study the CLI in a logical way.  Learning UI is faster than learning a CLI IMHO.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for everyone else, but command-line coding makes me feel like an uber-programming genius wizard hacker. So, yeah. Moar command-line, please. :P

Answer (score 11):

Stackoverflow is for *programming problems*. If a problem can be solved with a UI, it's pretty frequently not a programming problem. Sometimes we give users the benefit of the doubt and offer a programming solution instead of closing the question as off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

Some things that come to mind:

- there isn't always a UI solution; I'd say most SO questions aren't answerable with a UI
- the UI is only a layer on top, the actual value is typically stored in the file system anyway
- it's more concise and direct to answer with a line in a file instead of directing someone through a user interface which may or may not look completely different on his computer due to version differences or localisation
- there are many flexible ways in which you can modify a file on disk, but only one inflexible way of navigating UIs
- the user may not have access to a UI, but does have access to the file system (very typical of server configuration questions)
- due to all of the above, most experienced programmers/sysadmins/"professionals" prefer non-UI solutions and don't want the UI solution

If there are two ways to go about it, I'd always answer with the "low level" solution as the primary answer and maybe point out that the same thing can be accomplished via a UI as an extra.